# How to pass a parameters to cypher query Create Statement using Py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

For example:

```
cquery = """CREATE (u:User { Name: {username})"""     
data = graph.run(cquery, username=username)
```

Something like that but the query above I am getting cyphersynthax error could anyone help me?

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation: http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html -    it is very well explained how these statements work. It should be something like this: `cquery = "CREATE (u:User { Name: {username}})"` and 
`graph.run(cquery, username="username")`. I think also your `data` will be empty because of first, you do not return anything in your statement and second, the method `run` does not return anything.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, THAT Worked, i left the parantheses.